# Fresh install of Ubuntu crashes after booting

Tags: boot, crash

I'm trying to get a fresh install of Ubuntu to work on a Fujitsu Esprimo e910. I have prepared a USB installation media and the installation process went as usual. I installed Ubuntu to a SATA III SSD. After the installation is done, it asks me to reboot. But one or two seconds after the Ubuntu Desktop comes up on screen it crashes and boots again and the same thing will repeat itself for ever. I have the latest bios. I repeated the installation process multiple times. What could be wrong?!?

- Secure boot is disabled in the BIOS
- UEFI is enabled
- I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.2

Update:
I found out, that the problem must have something to do with the displays. The machine has DVI and display port. If I plug in a second monitor into the DisplayPort within the second Ubuntu comes up, it wont crash! If I have it plugged in before I turn on the machine, It wont boot. I remember, that the whole problem started after I first plugged in the second monitor. But after that, I have re-installed Ubuntu and the problem persists

Hardware configuration:
Fujitsu ESPRIMO E910
Intel® Core i5-3570
4 x 8GB DDR3 1600Mhz PC3-12800 Crucial RAM
Intenso 2,5" SSD SATA III, 120 GB

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in the BIOS? Does your machine have UEFI? If so, it should be enabled.  Did you enable downloads for the installation? What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Do not answer in the comments, rather edit the information into your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "enable downloads for the installation"?

Comment: And how would I do that? I have provided the information you asked for. I don't understand why UEFI or secure boot could be the reason if the system crashes after it has booted into Ubuntu.

Comment: When you install Ubuntu, there is a "Download updates" and "Install-third party software" check box. This updates the software while you are installing it. There can be many reasons why your installation is crashing and we have to eliminate them one at a time.

Comment: The machine was not connected to the network or internet during intallation. Should do it again with internet conection?

Comment: Yes, please try it.

Comment: I did so but the problem stays the same…

Comment: Can you boot into safe mode?

Comment: If I choose "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" in the boot menu, "Ubuntu with Linux 5.19.0-45-generic (recovery)", "resume", the system boots and does not crash! In this mode, the only display resolution is 800x600 and can't be changed. I have the feeling something with the graphics is causing the problem... Is der probably an issue with Intel HD-Grafik 2500 and Ubuntu?

Comment: Is [this Fujitsu](https://www.fujitsu.com/be/imagesgig5/prel-ds-ESPRIMO-E910-0Watt.pdf) your machine? Can you edit your hardware configuration into your question. I think you only have Intel graphics, or do you have an add-on NVIDIA card? Normally there should not be an issue with Intel graphics (I have Intel graphics only one my Dell laptop and it works fine). But maybe you have to change the driver. For this, we must determine what driver you have installed.

Comment: Yes, this is the machine, I have edited the hardware configuration into the question. No I dont have an NVIDIA card installed. how can I find out what the drivers are? If I do a sudo lshw -c video it gives me VGA compatible controller, Xeon E3 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller. It doesent say anything about Intel HD graphics. The reason for this might be, that I can only booz in safe mode and some graphics divers need a full graphical boot, so they might not be seen when booted in safe mode

Comment: Does the live session work without any problems? If so, it means basically that your machine is compatible with Linux, indeed the tech sheet says that it supports openSUSE. You can try using a VGA monitor with the VGA port as well. I also suggest to try an earlier version of Ubuntu such as 20.04

Comment: The life session works fine, just like the installation process but I have to pick "Try or install Ubuntu safe graphics". If I pick the first boot option "Try or install" it crashes. There is no VGA port on the machine, only DVI. I tried Open SUSE, it crashes during installation.

Comment: I tried Ubuntu 20.04: same problem

Comment: Another long shot, look in the BIOS and see if RAID is enabled, or if AHCI is enabled. Make sure it is AHCI and RAID is disabled. I'm assuming that you have deleted Windows. Otherwise it could be a driver problem or a Kernel problem.

Comment: I never used Windows on this machine. I bought it off ebay with no drive. The only drive inside is a brand new one that i put in

Comment: A final suggestion if you are able, install an Nvidia graphics card and check if it works after that. Also try Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: 23.04 is just the same. Why do you recomend NVIDIA over AMD? What is the best place to look up if older Radeon GPUs that i find on ebay will work in Ubuntu 22.04? Will the kernel support for example a HD3450?

Comment: [Here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-amd-nvidia-gpus-linux/) a link which explains the compatibility of AMD, Nvidia and Intel with Linux. You can find many reviews like this on the web and make your own informed choice.